# Fix the value of numeric input

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application where in there is numericInput box. Is there a way to limit the default value of it with additional condition

For example

```
num <- c(1,4,2,,7,9,3) # This is a random value
numericInput("ID","ID",value = )
```

In Value above, can we make a default random entry that is not there in `num` . Also the user should not be able to edit it

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you want the default value to be a random number?

Comment: Sorry . It is a Random value that is not present in num and the user should not be able to change it.

Comment: Make sense ?:)...........